# In NetBeans svn::commit - is this possible to get a warning when a commit message is the same as the last time?

Tags: svn, netbeans

I hope that maybe there is a plugin for that.

This happens to me all the time, I click SVN->subversion->commit->commit and in this moment I realize that I didn't update a commit message (NetBeans remembers recently used commit messages).

Is there any way NetBeans to warn me when I do this? Something like "You did not change the Commit Message, continue anyway?".